# how to pass custom data to Adobe launch Analytics

Tags: angular6, adobe, launch

I have a requirement, where i have to use the adobe launch to implement the analytics in my web page. clients have already share the custom variables to track certain events and props. can any one explain how to implement it in web application(angular 6+) .
**Note:**I have added the Launch cdn into index and am calling the _staellite variable to track. but have no idea on passing the custom props and evars.

Answer (score 0):

it may be that you will need to integrate Launch snippet code on top of your webpage / application.

Once you have done that, you would need to do the work in the Launch interface itself. 
Launch is loading the JS that you will write in the application (it is a Tag Management system).

So the job on the page is minimal as it just required to load the launch snippet. 
Should be similar to that :

Launch support the usage of Custom Javascript.
For more information : https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/launch/using/overview.html